# How to implement onTextChangedListenerItem to search an item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-volley

I am using [recyclerview](/questions/tagged/recyclerview) to display items on fragment. I have used[addtextchangedlistener](/questions/tagged/addtextchangedlistener) to implement searh functionality in my app.When I am going to type text in [edittext](/questions/tagged/edittext) all items in [recycler](/questions/tagged/recycler) view disappears and I am not able to get filtered results.  This is code for my[addtextchangedlistener](/questions/tagged/addtextchangedlistener)

```
private void addTextListener() {
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                 s=s.toString().toLowerCase();
                 final ArrayList<CurrentEntry> filter=new ArrayList<>();
                 for(int i=0;i<filter.size();i++)
                 {
                     final  String text=current.get(i).toString().toLowerCase();
                     if(text.contains(s))
                     {
                         filter.add(current.get(i));
                     }

                 }
                 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                 adapt=new NewAdapter(filter,getActivity());
                 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapt);
                 adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //filter(s.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my [jsonrequest](/questions/tagged/jsonrequest) using [volley](/questions/tagged/volley)

```
private void getData() {
        String json_req = "json_req";
        String url =getContext().getString(R.string.CURRENT_STATUS);


        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                       try
                       {

                           JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response.toString());
                           JSONArray data=object.getJSONArray("results");
                           for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++)
                           {
                               JSONObject json = data.getJSONObject(i);
                             final   CurrentEntry c=new CurrentEntry();
                               userUrl=json.getString("name");
                               JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, userUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                       try {
                                           String foodie_name=response.getString("username");
                                           c.setName(name);
                                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                       }
                                       adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                   }
                               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                   }
                               }
                               )

                               {
                                   @Override
                                   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                                       Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                                       String credentials = ""+":"+"";
                                       String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                                       headers.put("Content-type", "application/json");
                                       headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                                       return headers;
                                   }
                               };
                               AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request,second_req);
                               c.setPeople(json.getString("my_people"));
                               String temp=json.getString("my_timetime");
                               temp=temp.substring(11);
                               temp=temp.substring(0,temp.length()-4);
                               c.setEstimate(temp);
                               current.add(c);

                            }

                           recyclerView.setAdapter(adapt);
                           adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       }
                       catch (JSONException e)
                       {

                       }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }

                })
        {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                String credentials = ""+":"+"";
                String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                headers.put("Content-type", "application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, json_req);
    }
```

How to solve this to get filtered results in [recyclerview](/questions/tagged/recyclerview).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code

```
adapt=new NewAdapter(filter,getActivity());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapt);
adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

NewAdapter is not required to create every time text is changed. Instead, try changing the values of adapter list and call notifyDataSetChanged() like below.

```
adapt.filter=filter;
adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and add these lines in your onCreate()

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
adapt=new NewAdapter(filter,getActivity());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapt);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are calling the below code again and again;

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
adapt=new NewAdapter(data,getActivity());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapt);
adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Just write this code once in onCreateView of your Fragment:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
adapt=new NewAdapter(data,getActivity());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapt);
```

Now in your adapter class you will need to have a setter for data which can be used to set the updated data which you get from your API against your search filter in your view. And post that you will just need to call adapt.notifyDataSetChanged():

```
adapt.setNewData(data);
adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I have changed code but still not getting filtered results. The issue of dissappearing all records when typing something in edittext is solved now

Comment: @SatyamGondhale Please try to add logs to search.addTextChangedListener method. This may be because of the response time of the API call. What you can do to solve it, you can maintain a boolean in your fragment that will keep the state of if any API call is in progress currently or not. So whenever you make a request set it true before initiate request and set it false post result(success or failure both) and don't forget to check the boolean before making a new search request.